# How to create an n-bit multiplexer?

Tags: vhdl, multiplexer

I'm needing to create a 4 bit, 16 input multiplexer. I know I could describe this as a long list of `S => when "0000"` etc.. but I think that's not very clean, and I'd like to opt for a generic n-bit multiplexer so I can reuse it later for more inputs or whatever.

How would you do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's like this:

```
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
...
signal din :std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);  -- must be "downto 0"
signal sel :std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
...
dout <= din(conv_integer(sel));
```

Hope that helps!

Addition:
If you'd need a multiple bit wide mux then...

```
type data_bus_array is array(7 downto 0) of std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
signal din :data_bus_array;
signal dout :std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
signal sel :std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
...
dout <= din(conv_integer(sel));
```

This is where VHDL gets a little bit wordy, since sometimes it's not "compact" to fill in that data bus array just to do a simple mux.  But, there you have it...

Comment: Wow. Now that's just too easy. what if you wanted multiple bit inputs though?

Comment: @Earlz  I added multi-bit-wide stuff to my answer, above.

Comment: Nice. Would've been a bit better if you had added generics in, but that's pretty easy to change around

Comment: You have numeric_std - yay!  But then you need "to_integer", not "conv_integer".  Then, why not make sel an "unsigned" type?